# How to find sales per hour between two date

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, aggregate, average

Suppose I have 5 records for a sales table.

```
ID    Name    datetime_col
1     ABC     2016-09-15 02:07:56
2     HSJ     2016-09-31 11:45:45
3     JSD     2016-11-26 07:09:56
4     JUH     2016-12-31 12:00:00
5     IGY     2017-01-13 14:00:07
```

I want to find how many records are there in sales table for each hour between 2016-09-15 AND 2017-01-13
Then result should be like

```
Hour                 sales_at_this_hour
2016-09-15 01:00:00  0
2016-09-15 02:00:00  1
2016-09-15 03:00:00  0
...
...
2017-01-13 01:00:00  0
2017-01-13 02:00:00  0
2017-01-13 03:00:00  0
....

2017-01-13 14:00:00  1
```

Then find the average of sales_at_this_hour using MySQL

Comment: can you please give me link of question having solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022276/filter-between-two-dates-mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgaps-and-islands%5D+and+%5Bmysql%5D

Comment: @shmosel Me too I miss read the question. Finally, I understood your "gaps-and-islands" tag. Good catch! I was about to write it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @MasterDJon no one link is relevant to my question

Comment: @shmosel AND OP Yes. The first link in the search of shmosel. It has to be adjusted a bit, but not so much. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725374/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-hours-dates-in-range

Comment: I don't think gaps and islands has anything to do with this problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Then where are those zeros coming from?

Comment: @shmosel They're coming from the left side join of a calendar table with his original data.

Comment: is there any solution without stored procedure and with the limited query. Because the answer I'm seeing will take longer time?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: sorry not fully understand the question at first.

Use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
select 
    DATE_FORMAT(datetime_col, '%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00') as date,
    count(id) as count 
from table_name
group by date;
```

Get result with hours that has sales_at_this_hour > 1 (not exactly what you ask for)

```
datetime_col        count
2016-02-04 05:00:00 5
2016-02-04 07:00:00 1
2016-02-04 08:00:00 5
2016-02-04 10:00:00 10
2016-02-04 11:00:00 1
```

Provide `start_date` and `end_date`, and then use [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) to calculate total time interval for the average calculation.

```
set @start_date = '2016-01-01', @end_date = '2017-01-01';
select 
    DATE_FORMAT(group_by_date.datetime, '%h:00:00') as hour, 
    AVG(group_by_date.count) / DATEDIFF(@end_date, @start_date) as average 
from  (
    select 
        DATE_FORMAT(created_dtm, '%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00') as datetime,
        count(id) as count 
    from table_name
    where created_dtm > @start_date
    and created_dtm < @end_date
    group by datetime
    ) group_by_date
group by hour;
```

For each hour,
average sale count per day =  total sale count / total days

```
hour        average
01:00:00    0.03841209
02:00:00    0.01653005
03:00:00    0.0306716
04:00:00    0.01147541
05:00:00    0.01179831
```

Comment: If I want select average, then there should be only one record for all the hours between two dates